# Symfony ManyToMany Form is not valid

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two project and I install the same version. But in new(clear project) work fine and for old project don't work form is not valid - form->children->elements->(language, specialities, platforms)->error->message=This value is not valid. And I don't know for one project work fine and another form is not valid and end, I try for another entity in old project for relation ManyToMany create form but again form is not valid, some global error, help how its solved?

```
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
```

and I create controller for entity skill help with:

```
app/console doctrine:generate:crud --with-write
```

and I don't change

```
/**
 * Creates a new Skill entity.
 *
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Skill();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('skill_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return $this->render('ArtelProfileBundle:Skill:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

form

```
class SkillType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('skill')
        ->add('language')
        ->add('platforms')
        ->add('specialities')
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Skill'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'artel_profilebundle_skill';
}
}
```

and entity for all this

```
class Skill
{
use Timestampable;
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @Expose()
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages", inversedBy="skills", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $language;

/**
 * @var \Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeDirectoryPlatforms
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CodeDirectoryPlatforms", inversedBy="skills", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $platforms;

/**
 * @var \Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeDirectorySpecialities
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CodeDirectorySpecialities", inversedBy="skills", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $specialities;
```